# how can I import multiple csv files with selected columns using textscan?

Tags: matlab, csv, textscan

I have a large number of csv files to be processed. I only want the selected columns in each file and then load all the files from a certain folder and then output as one combined file. Here are my codes running with errors.... Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
data_directory = 'C:\Users\...\data';
numfiles = 17;
for n = 1:numfiles
    filepath = [data_directory,'data_', num2str(n),'_output.csv'];
    fid = fopen (filepath, 'rt');
    wanted_columns= [2 3 4 5 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 35 36 41 42 44 45 59 61];
    format = [];
    columns = 109;
for i = 1 : columns;
    if any (i == wanted_columns)
        format = [format '%s'];
    else
        format = [format '%*s'];
    end
end
    data = textscan(fid, format, 'Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',1);
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: What are the errors that you get?

Comment: @ThijsW  
The errors are:??? Error using ==> textscan
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier. 
Error in ==> data_import_fail at 16
    data = textscan(fid, format, 'Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check whether the file is opened correctly. The error message seems to indicate that this is not the case. If it is not, check if the `filepath` is correct.

```
fid = fopen (filepath, 'rt');
if fid == -1
    error('Failed to open file');
end
```

If the error is thrown here, you know that there was a problem with `'fopen'`.

Ofcourse I don't know which files are on your computer, but I assume the `'...'` in the filename is not in your actual matlab file, only in your question on SO.
But could it be that you repeat the word `'data'`, while the actual filename only contains `'data'` once? You code now will result in filenames like `''C:\Users\...\datadata_1_output.csv'`. Maybe `'data'` should be removed in `data_directory` or in `filepath = ...`?

Comment: Hi, this is very helpful. I changed all the repeat words that may cause confusion and it works now.Thank you very much!!!--Jackie

Comment: Could i ask one more question about how to continue outputting my dataset as one file? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Didn't see your comment before. Ask away. Probably best to create a new question on this website, to keep things nice and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way how you can setup the format string in a vectorized manner:

```
fcell = repmat({'%*s '},1,n_columns);
fcell(wanted_columns) = {'%s '};
formatstr = [fcell{:}];
```

Notice `format` is a build-in function in MATLAB, and it's better not to be used for variable name.